# IS it ok to have 20 activities in an app?

Tags: android-activity

I am trying to make a  basic kids app. I have 20 questions to be asked, kid will tap on the right colour and once he does so , next question should appear.

My questions is shall I keep changing layout of the same activity or shall I call 2 and create 20 different actvities for 20 different colour questions. What isthe Best Practice?

Comment: Yes you may have 20 in one app. Is it a good idea in your scenario? no

Answer (score 1):

one activity is enough . you can just change the texview values of questions and answers and manipulate colors if you want too. as soon as user hits next button check with answer ,add it to score or add just 0 then change values for next question.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to create new button you do just change the button name or question    1.user open the app   2. there is a start quiz button 3. user press the start quiz  button 4. we do four things (A)creating a hash-table  of questions giving it 1.2.3...ids, creating hashtable of right answers giving same ids 1.2.3.. then two more tables with fake answers giving same ids (B) when we are done doing this we start with first question. (c) using id 1 from table 1 get the the value and assign it to question or the first button i guess. (d) using id 1 get value from table 2 which our right answers table assign it to one of 3 buttons (e) now get value from 3 and 4 table which is our  fake answer table using id 1 n assign to other two buttons.5 now our question 1 is ready and wait for user to click on one of three buttons. 6. lets say user click button 3 . 7 using button id we get button name which the answer user gave us we match it with our table 2 id 1 8. if it matches user giving the right answer we add 1 point to user score and move to next question which will be  question number+1 so 2 then will repeat same from step C to E but this time we will use id 2 . so every time user answer we go to next question using +1 with question number until be get at 20. 9. if answer does not match we add nothing to score move to next question. When question number reaches 20 we finish we hide all button and show a textview with user's score